# Storing images in database results in partial image

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to store images in a sql server database. I've got a column in an Image table which stores the data and is of type varbinary(max). I'm using NHibernate to access the database.

The loading of the image into the code and converting it to a buffer array works fine. When I store the image in the database, no matter what size image above 30kb that I put in, only part of the image is saved.

I checked the data stored in the database and all images have the same amount of data stored so my guess is that something is limiting the size of the byte[] that can be held in the column.

When I pull the data out of the database and display the image on the screen, it shows the top portion of the image only.

What could be wrong?

**Update:**
I checked the size of the data in the varbinary(max) column and all data entries are 8000bytes.

Here's the code:

Table Creation:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Image')
            CREATE TABLE [Image]
            (
                [ImageId]                       INT IDENTITY(1,1)       NOT NULL,
                [FileName]                      NVARCHAR(MAX)           NOT NULL,
                [ImageData]                     VARBINARY(MAX)          NOT NULL,
                [Caption]                       NVARCHAR(MAX)           NULL,
                CONSTRAINT PK_ImageId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ImageId ASC)
                ON [PRIMARY]
            )
```

Fluent mapping:

```
public ImageMap()
    {
        Id(x=>x.Id,"ImageId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Caption);
        Map(x => x.FileName);
        Map(x => x.Data).Column("ImageData");
        HasMany(x => x.ArticleImages).KeyColumn("ImageId").Inverse();
        HasOne(x => x.Thumbnail).PropertyRef(r=>r.Image).Cascade.All();
    }
```

NHibernate entity class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Image : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Image's name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Image's Caption
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Caption { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binary data for the image
    /// </summary>
    public virtual byte[] Data { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Link to article
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IEnumerable<ArticleImage> ArticleImages { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The thumbnail for the image
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ImageThumbnail Thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you want an answer in text form or actual code? If you want code I'd suggest you post some for us too...

Comment: Fixed it.

Changed the imagedata mapping to 
        

     Map(x => x.Data).Column("ImageData").CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it.

Changed the imagedata mapping to

Map(x => x.Data).Column("ImageData").CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Length(160000);

For some reason, the data was being truncated to 8000 bytes via the nhibernate mapping. Adding this fixed it.

Comment: i've got the same problem, and adding those properties won't fix it, data will still be stored at 8000b maximum, any idea what else could be causing this, besides the mapping configuration?

Comment: Worked for me. With SQL 2008, NHibernate 3.2 and mapping by code